# how to find difference between elements of two data arrays of different sizes?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataset, python-xarray, weather

I am trying to find daily temperature anomalies (difference between daily temperature and average temperature for that day). I have two arrays, one with daily temperature for 20 years worth of data (7300 elements), and one with average temperatures for every day (365 elements). I want to find the daily temperature anomalies for each day in my data array with 20 years of data. I want a final array that consists of 7300 elements each of which is the difference between the temperature observation for that day and the average temperature for the calendar day. Here is what I currently have:

```
Tanom=[]
for month,day in zip(months[0:366],days[0:366]):
    which_days=(months==month)&(days==day)
    anom=Tmax[which_days]-Tclim[which_days]
    Tanom.append(anom)
Tanom=xr.concat(Tanom,dim="time")
```

Tmax is my 7300 element data array with daily temperatures and Tclim is my 365 element data array with average daily temperatures. When I try this code I get the following error Boolean array size 7300 is used to index array with shape (366, 277, 349).

Comment: sounds like a `merge` job

Comment: what is the type of elements in Tclim? Datetime? Could you show an example of your data? Like a few rows of each array?

Comment: They are netcdf files that I am using as data arrays with xarray: 
Here is Tmax:
xarray.DataArray'air'time: 365 y: 277 x: 349
array([[[299.5004 , 299.54083, 299.54083, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [299.5004 , 299.5004 , 299.54083, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
Here is Tclim:
xarray.DataArray'air'time: 7300 y: 277 x: 349
array([[[299.5004 , 299.54083, 299.54083, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [299.5004 , 299.5004 , 299.54083, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],